# Using a script to transform column values in a Table

Tags: php, javascript, database, perl

I'm new to scripting so stick with me. I'm trying to create a script that will transform the column values in my Table. I'm currently using SQL Management Studio.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a column with account numbers in this form:

```
R12345
M23456
T12345
```

I'm trying to convert the first letter to a sequence of numbers then keep the remaining numbers. For example:

```
R12345 to 10012345
M23456 to 20023456
T12345 to 30012345
```

I cant seem to find the file to run this script off of sad The reason I'm doing this is to create a 1 to 1 relation with this table and another table that is in the form of just those numbers.I've been stuck on this problem for some time now
I have way too many records in this table to do it myself. Any thoughts on how I should go about doing this? Any particular DBMS or scripting language that I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE accounts_table
SET account_number=CONCAT(
  CASE 
    WHEN SUBSTR(account_number,1,1)='R' THEN '100'
    WHEN SUBSTR(account_number,1,1)='M' THEN '200'
    WHEN SUBSTR(account_number,1,1)='T' THEN '300'
  END,
  SUBSTR(account_number,2)
)
```